# Need help with friendly URL's in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I'm creating som custom templates in Wordpress and I'm passing some data in the URL's.

Currently my URL looks like this:
http://www.mysite.com/designers/?id=43&name=designer+name

The URL contains designer ID and designer name.

I would really like to use this:
http://www.mysite.com/designers/designer+name/

My permalink structure is set to `/%category%/%postname%/`

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I've looked at http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks, but not become any wiser.

I got two questions:

1. Is there any point in changing the above URL regarding SEO
2. How can I get the "pretty" URL?

Comment: You might be better off switching to something like Drupal, which is designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: Drupal is a good CMS but very hard to learn - I've tried.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com is the ideal target for this question.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Didn't know about that one. It doesn't look that active though - hopefully ppl will catch on.

Comment: @ceejayoz - I coded for Drupal for 2 years, then switch to WordPress and will *never* go back. Drupal is very too over-architected and ends up being easy to get 85% done but almost impossible to finish the last 15%. At least in my experience.

Comment: @Andy Lester - Kudos for mentioning!

Comment: @Steven - WordPress answers may not be as *"active"* as SO, but we boast a 92% answer rate; try us out!

Comment: @MikeSchinkel I actively develop in both.

Comment: @ceejayoz - After 2 years working in Drupal I did a WordPress project with full intention to return to Drupal. But by the end of the WordPress project I reflected on how pleasant it was to work with WordPress and then I realized I hated working in Drupal. I guess to each his own, but I personally couldn't recommend Drupal in good faith to anyone. JMTCW. (P.S. With every new .1 release WordPress is continuing to erase all the remaining reasons people can claim Drupal is better. Custom Post Types were a *huge* step.)

Comment: @ceejayoz - BTW, I'm a moderator over at the SO sister site WordPress Answers (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) so from that my allegiance is pretty clear. :)

Comment: @MikeSchnikel: Anything I can do to help keep the WordPress questions off of main SO is a win. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Steven, quite an interesting topic. I went through it last year on my real estate project in WordPress. There are tonnes of ways to apply some customizations to your permalinks, including all the new features in WordPress 3.0 and above, but as I figured out, the key is of course to sort of "hard-code" them.

In WordPress it's done pretty much the same way as you would do it in Apache, only with a few exceptions. Read through the [WP_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Rewrite) article, it should pretty much explain everything. With this approach I managed to get permalinks like this:

```
domain.com/browse/
domain.com/browse/country/
domain.com/browse/country/region/
domain.com/property/country/region/property-name/
```

Where `country` and `region` are one custom taxonomy which is hierarchical. It took me a while but it seems to work fine now, even with the latest changes to the core code.